# Estimate of Wasserstein distance and flow of vector fields under particular assumptions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, optimal-transportation

Let $\mu$ be a compactly supported absolutely continuous probability measure. Let $v,u$ be Lipschitz vector fields. For a vector field $w$ recall that $\Phi_t^w$ denotes its flow.

A classical estimate on the Wasserstein distance $W_1(\Phi^{v+u}_t\# \mu, \mu)$ is $$W_1(\Phi^{v+u}_t\# \mu, \mu)\le t \|v+u\|_{C^0}.$$

Can this estimate be improved if we additionally assume $\Phi_t^{v}\#\mu = \mu$ and $\mathrm{supp}(u) \subset \omega$?

For example, can we show that the right hand-side can be made small (having fixed $t>0$) depending on $\omega$ (for example, depending on $\mathrm{meas}(\omega)$ or $\mathrm{diam}(\omega)$)?